# Editor.js rendering/outputting two editors in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, editorjs

I'm using Editor.js in React (Next.js) & have the original package, not the 3rd party wrappers for react.

For a reason I don't know, it is rendering/showing/outputting two `codex-editores` on the page! Both of them are working correctly and independently.

### Screenshot (I added borders to show the area)

[image: screenshot of the problem]

## Codes

##### index.jsx

```
import EditorJS from "@editorjs/editorjs";
import css from "./removeme.module.scss" // just to see the area;

export default function index(params) {
   const editor = new EditorJS({
      holder: "editorjs",
   });

   return (
      <>
         <h1>New Note</h1>
         <div className={css["editor-area"]} id="editorjs" />
      </>
   );
}
```

##### _app.js

```
function SafeHydrate({ children }) {
   return <div suppressHydrationWarning>{typeof window === "undefined" ? null : children}</div>;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return (
      <SafeHydrate>
         <Body>
            <Sidebar items={SidebarLinks} />
            <Page>
               <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
         </Body>
      </SafeHydrate>
   );
}

export default MyApp;
```

## What I tried

- Commenting `<SafeHydrate>` and render the page normally: **no luck**. (I added SafeHydrate so I can use `window` API and also disable SSR)
- Removing my custom CSS (the borders): **no luck**.
- Removing `id="editorjs"` from `<div>`: **nothing shows up**.

## Additional Notes

The page `localhost:3001/notes/editor` is only accessible if visited from sidebar menu (SPA-like). I mean, it shows 'window is not defined' if opened directly.

What's causing the problem?

Comment: Had the same issue some weeks ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990522/editorjs-always-renders-two-editors

Comment: Strange I didn't find your question before posting mine @PRSHL. Also, it's not just 2, I tried again & see it can be 4 or 5 or more editors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `useEffect` solves the issue since it only runs after the initial page render:

```
export default function index(params) {
   useEffect(() => {
      const editor = new EditorJS({
         holder: "editorjs",
      });
   }, []);
   
   return (
      <>
         <h1>New Note</h1>
         <div className={css["editor-area"]} id="editorjs" />
      </>
   );
}
```

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563285/editorjs-in-nextjs-not-able-to-load-plugins for furhter configuration and usage of editor.js + next.js.